# How do I write a UI Test for verifying my macOS app launches? (Xcode 15, macOS 13.1)

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-ui-testing

I'm looking to start simple and have a basic UI test that verifies my app launches. What I found so far doesn't seem to work though...

What I have is this:

````
func testAppDoesLaunch() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    XCTAssertTrue(app.exists, "App did launch."
}```


The error I'm getting is:

testAppDoesLaunch(): Device is not configured for UI testing - use of XCUIApplication is not supported. This can happen when XCUIApplication is used in a unit test bundle instead of a UI test bundle. (NSInternalInconsistencyException)
````

Comment: How have you defined your test class?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes I have it defined as:

import XCTest

class MyAppUITests: XCTestCase {}

Comment: Do you happen to be using Detox? That's the only mention I can seem to find of this error. https://github.com/wix/Detox/pull/3975

Comment: Or how about this? Did you possibly not set your bundle up correctly? https://semaphoreci.com/blog/ui-testing-swift